# Is condensation a concern on duct work that's enclosed in a soffit?

Tags: hvac, condensation

In my 1973 town-home, which is basically a ranch style layout, there's a single hallway that runs parallel to the length of the unit, bisecting the living area from the bedrooms.  It is the only location in the house that has a 7 foot soffit.

That soffit, which is 36" wide and 12" tall contains the main supply duct from the A/C unit.  It's one long, straight run with no turns, and only a few branches.

This is a flat roof (approx 11-12" joists) with insulation between the drywall and the roof underlayment.

In the case of the soffit, there's the roof, then the insulation, then the main supply duct, then drywall.

During my renovations, the airspace inside the soffit has been exposed to the elements.  Yesterday, I discovered pooling water on the top of the air supply duct from condensation.  It's monsoon season in Arizona, and it's relatively humid.  So, there's water there.  I'm wondering how long that water has been showing up there.

If the soffit had been undisturbed and contained, would condensation be an issue such that I would need to wrap the duct work with insulation, or should I not worry about it as it might not be an issue once the soffit is sealed from the outside elements, thereby removing the introduction of humid air to the space?

Comment: is your air handler coil icing up ?

Comment: "airspace inside the soffit has been exposed to the elements" as in roof-off exposed or just that the drywall around the soffit has been removed? If you mean just the drywall has been removed, then that's really no different than any other day since it was installed.